# How to import data and set columns from .csv in python? command

Tags: python, pandas, csv, input, import

I have  a question about a code. I would like to ask you something abput a code. I have a .csv file with no header 10 columns with numbers (float). I would like to make calculations between 1st and 9th column, using an equation. How could I firstly set/declare each column ??
For example I would like to set the first column as "X", the second as "X1" etc.

I have written only this until now

```
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.read_csv('ALL.csv', usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], header=None)
print(df)
```

I am new in python and I need your help.

could you help me please?

Comment: For example in Matlab I set as : importdata('ALL.csc'); X=data.(:,1).

Comment: df['eq']=df.apply(lambda row: row['col1']*row['col9'],axis=1) suppose your data header has col1 and col9 text at first row. Now we have new column with name eq which you can filter. Note: Times shows sample function, so you can replace it with what ever you want

Comment: Finally, the solution is: `import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.read_csv('ALL.csv', usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], header=None)                    X=df[1]' etc